# Run command on USB device disconnect Windows

Tags: windows, usb, connection, hid

On a linux system, I could reasonably easily add a rule to /etc/udev/rules.d to run a command on connection or disconnection of a USB device. On windows (win10 version 1607), however, I have found no easy way to do this. The device itself identifies a USB HID-compliant Device and a USB Input device and I have its vendor ID and product ID, but I cannot for the life of me work out how to execute a program/script/command/anything really on disconnection. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how would one do so?

Comment: [Logging when someone connects or removes a USB device to/from a Windows machine](//superuser.com/q/849950)

Comment: Ooh - that looks interesting. Maybe using the logparser and piping the output of that into some other script that filters it for USB events might work. Cheers for that.

Oh how much easier this is on debian linux